# TypeScript type assertion generates a message: The character ">" is not valid inside a JSX element

Tags: typescript, jsx, tsx, type-assertion

In this code:

```tsx
export const createCategoriesParams = (filters: string[]) => {
  const tags = [...filters].filter(i => i !== 'All');
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
  let row = <any>[];

  tags.forEach(item => {
    row.push(`tag=${item}`);
  });

  return row.join('&');
};
```

when I run my esbuild script, it throws error in:

```
tags.forEach((item, ind) => {
```

saying

> The character ">" is not valid inside a JSX element

any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Exactly -  `<any>` is interpreted as a JSX opening tag (would need `</any>` to close it), so everything afzerwards is now text inside the tag, but `>` isn't valid there (if it really were text it'd have to be `&gt;`).

Answer (score 3):

The same error appeared in my code after `eslint-loader` update. In my case  `eslint-loader` [changed behaviour](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/esbuild-loader/releases/tag/v3.0.0) so it automatically knows how to handle each file (js, jsx, ts, tsx). So I needed to update my webpack config

from

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'esbuild-loader',
    options: {
        target: 'esnext',
        loader: 'tsx'
    }

}
```

to

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'esbuild-loader',
    options: {
        target: 'esnext'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The TypeScript handbook warns](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator):

> Recall how to write a type assertion:
>
> ```ts
> const foo = <foo>bar;
> ```
>
> This asserts the variable `bar` to have the type `foo`. Since TypeScript also uses angle brackets for type assertions, combining it with JSX’s syntax would introduce certain parsing difficulties. As a result, TypeScript disallows angle bracket type assertions in `.tsx` files.
>
> Since the above syntax cannot be used in `.tsx` files, an alternate type assertion operator should be used: `as`. The example can easily be rewritten with the `as` operator.
>
> ```ts
> const foo = bar as foo;
> ```

In your case, the line at fault is `let row = <any>[];` which, taken literally, should be written as `let row = [] as any;`.  Though `let row: string[] = [];` would be preferable to either.